# How do I do "if defined()" from ruby in puppet 2.7?

Tags: ruby, puppet

In puppet 2.7, I can do this in a puppet manifest to avoid defining the same thing twice:

```
if !defined( File['/root/.ssh'] ) {
  # define a thing
}
```

I've got a ruby manifest defined like this:

```
define "mything", :app do
  # do a thing
end
```

How do I do the equivalent of the "!defined()" test from within the `#define` block?

Answer (score 2):

It is generally advisable to

- not use the `defined` function, because your manifest can become non-deterministic
- not write manifests in the Ruby DSL because it is discontinued after the 2.x releases of Puppet

Generally, try to encapsulate this kind of resource in a simple class so that you can

```
include site::root_ssh_dir
```

wherever you need to make sure it exists.

Comment: I *already have* a significant amount of ruby DSL I can't just delete.  Not using it isn't an option available right now; what I need to do is avoid a duplicate node declaration from ruby.  Should I be declaring a class per resource, and including them all?

Comment: Yes, either that, or you settle for **virtual resources** and realize them where they are needed.